# Updating Menu Items In UIMenuController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview, menuitem

I want to update menu items in tableview menu item controller as now I am getting these only
[image]

I have implemented this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let forword = UIMenuItem(title: "Demo", action: #selector(self.demo))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems?.append(forword)
        UIMenuController.shared.update()
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.clearAllSelectedCell()
    }
```

But my requirement is to make this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: yes i have but I want these two option more in menu controller along with them

Comment: Do you want Forward and Delete in addition to the standard items, or instead of?

Comment: yes i want in addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.  create protocol to provide control into your view controller :

public protocol MenuItemDelegate {
    func copyAction(cell: UITableViewCell)
    func forwordAction(cell: UITableViewCell)
    func deleteAction(cell: UITableViewCell)
}

2.  create a custom table cell:

        class MyTableCell: UITableViewCell {

            var menuItemDelegate: MenuItemDelegate!

            var isCopyEnable = true
            var isForwardEnable = true
            var isDeleteEnable = true


            override func awakeFromNib() {
                super.awakeFromNib()
            }

            func setUpmenu(){
                let menu = UIMenuController.shared
                let forword = UIMenuItem(title: "Forward", action: #selector(self.forword(_:)))
                let delete = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(self.deleteAction(_:)))
                menu.menuItems = [forword,delete]
                if !isDeleteEnable{
                    menu.menuItems?.remove(at: (menu.menuItems?.index(of: delete))!)
                }
                if !isForwardEnable{
                    menu.menuItems?.remove(at: (menu.menuItems?.index(of: forword))!)
                }
                menu.update()
            }

            override public func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
                UIPasteboard.general.string = accessibilityValue
                menuItemDelegate.copyAction(cell: self)
                UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
            }

            @objc public func forword(_ sender: Any?) {
                menuItemDelegate.forwordAction(cell: self)
                UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
            }

            @objc public func deleteAction(_ sender: Any?) {
                menuItemDelegate.deleteAction(cell: self)
                UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
            }

            override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
                return (action == #selector(copy(_:))  || action == #selector(forword(_:)) || action == #selector(deleteAction(_:)))
            }
    }

3. Implement in view controller as like : 


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell
    cell.isForwardEnable = false
    cell.setUpmenu()
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

It will help you to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code…

- Don't use `UIMenuController.shared.menuItems?.append`, just set `menuItems`
- Don't do that in `shouldShowMenuForRowAt`, just do it once in `viewDidLoad`
- You don't need to `setMenuVisible`

And most importantly

- The action for your menu item must be a method on your table view cell subclass.

So, in your case…

Your table view controller should have these methods…

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let forward = UIMenuItem(title: "Forward", action: #selector(MyCell.menuItemTapped(_ :)))
    let delete = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(MyCell.menuItemTapped(_ :)))
    UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [forward, delete]
    UIMenuController.shared.update()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

and your cell should have…

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    @objc func menuItemTapped(_ sender: UIMenuController) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ashley you have added it in view did load. What if I need different menu at different cell?

Comment: In that case do it in `shouldShowMenuForRowAt`

Comment: I have done that but it is not showing could you help me out

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let forword = UIMenuItem(title: "Demo", action: #selector(self.demo))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems?.append(forword)
        UIMenuController.shared.update()
        return true
    }

Comment: Please read my answer again. _"The action for your menu item must be a method on your table view cell subclass."_

Comment: I was kind of stuck in updating edit menu of WKWebview and it turned out what @AshleyMills said - the action must be a method on a view class - was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps, to achieve the custom items on long press.

1. Paste the below code in viewDidload method
   let reply = UIMenuItem(title: "Reply", action: #selector(MessageCollectionViewCell.reply(_ :)))
   let edit = UIMenuItem(title: "Edit", action: #selector(MessageCollectionViewCell.edit(_ :)))
   let forward = UIMenuItem(title: "Forward", action: #selector(MessageCollectionViewCell.forward(_ :)))
   UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [reply, edit, forward]
   UIMenuController.shared.update()
2. Extension for your custom cell
   extension MessageCollectionViewCell {

   @objc func reply(_ sender: Any?) {
       // Get the collectionView
       if let collectionView = self.superview as? UICollectionView {
           // Get indexPath
           if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: self) {
               // Trigger action
               collectionView.delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, performAction: #selector(MessageCollectionViewCell.reply(_:)), forItemAt: indexPath, withSender: sender)
           }
       }
   }

   @objc func edit(_ sender: Any?) {
       // Get the collectionView
       if let collectionView = self.superview as? UICollectionView {
           // Get indexPath
           if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: self) {
               // Trigger action
               collectionView.delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, performAction: #selector(MessageCollectionViewCell.edit(_:)), forItemAt: indexPath, withSender: sender)
           }
       }
   }

   @objc func forward(_ sender: Any?) {
       // Get the collectionView
       if let collectionView = self.superview as? UICollectionView {
           // Get indexPath
           if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: self) {
               // Trigger action
               collectionView.delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, performAction: #selector(MessageCollectionViewCell.forward(_:)), forItemAt: indexPath, withSender: sender)
           }
       }
   }

}

3. Add this code inside your controller, in my case In doing this (class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController{})

   // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   // MARK: - Handle Long Press Action
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
       return true
   }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
       print(action.description)
       let message = messages[indexPath.section]
       //let message = messagesDataSource.messageForItem(at: indexPath, in: messagesCollectionView)

   ```
   if action == NSSelectorFromString("reply:") {
       return true
   }
   else if action == NSSelectorFromString("edit:") {
       return true

   }
   else if action == NSSelectorFromString("forward:") {
       return true
   }
   else {
       return super.collectionView(collectionView, canPerformAction: action, forItemAt: indexPath, withSender: sender)
   }
   ```

   }

   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {

   ```
   if action == NSSelectorFromString("reply:") {
       print("reply item here!!")
   }
   else if action == NSSelectorFromString("edit:") {
       print("edit item here!!")
   }
   else if action == NSSelectorFromString("forward:") {
       print("forward item here!!")
   }
   else {
       super.collectionView(collectionView, performAction: action, forItemAt: indexPath, withSender: sender)
   }
   ```

   }